# Table not created with hbm2ddl.auto=update in Hibernate 5

Tags: mysql, hibernate, tomcat, hbm2ddl, hibernate-5.x

The database table is **NOT** auto-created by the `<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>` settings in `hibernate-cfg.xml`, with the following combination:

**Java 8 + Tomcat 8 + MySQL + Hibernate 5**

1. Java version:

   ```
   java version "1.8.0_45"
   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b14)
   Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)
   ```
2. MySQL version:

   ```
   mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.16, for osx10.7 (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
   ```
3. Tomcat version:

   ```
   apache-tomcat-8.0.22
   ```
4. pom.xml snippets:

   ```
   <dependency>
     <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
     <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
     <version>2.1.0</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
     <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
     <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
     <version>1.1</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
     <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
     <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
     <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
     <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
     <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
     <version>5.0.3.Final</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
     <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
     <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
     <version>5.0.3.Final</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
     <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
     <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
     <version>5.0.3.Final</version>
   </dependency>
   ```
5. Entity class:

   ```
   package com.test.entity;

   import java.util.Date;

   import javax.persistence.Column;
   import javax.persistence.Entity;
   import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
   import javax.persistence.Id;
   import javax.persistence.Table;
   import javax.persistence.Temporal;
   import javax.persistence.TemporalType;

   import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;

   @Entity
   @Table( name = "EVENTS" )
   public class Event {
       @Id
       @GeneratedValue(generator="increment")
       @GenericGenerator(name="increment", strategy = "increment")
       private Long id;

       private String title;

       @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
       @Column(name = "EVENT_DATE")
       private Date date;

       public Event() {}

       public Long getId() { return id; }
       private void setId(Long id) { this.id = id; }
       public Date getDate() { return date; }
       public void setDate(Date date) { this.date = date; }
       public String getTitle() { return title; }
       public void setTitle(String title) { this.title = title; }
   }
   ```
6. Hibernate `SessionFactory` initialization:

   ```
   String resource = "hibernate.cfg.xml";
   Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
   configuration.configure(resource);
   ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
   SessionFactory sessionFactoryCore = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
   ```
7. hibernate.cfg.xml:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC 
           "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" 
           "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd"> 
   <hibernate-configuration>
     <session-factory>
       <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
       <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
       <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test</property>
       <property name="connection.username">mysqluser</property>
       <property name="connection.password">******</property>
       <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
       <property name="hibernate.max_fetch_depth">3</property>
       <mapping class="com.test.entity.Event" />
     </session-factory>
   </hibernate-configuration>
   ```

**HOWEVER**, the table was created into MySQL database, with the following combination:

**Java 8 + Tomcat 8 + MySQL + Hibernate 4**

Everything same as above, except in pom.xml, I was using hibernate 4 instead of 5:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
  <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
  <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
  <version>4.3.11.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
  <version>4.3.11.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
  <version>4.3.11.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

What am I missing in Hibernate 5?

Answer (score 12):

We faced a similar problem after upgrading to Hibernate 5.x and this was solved by changing the *dialect* to **org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect**.

Answer (score 1):

add `<property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action">`create`</property>` in your hibernate config file.

Comment: Some explanation would greatly improve the quality of the answer and help other users who may encounter similar problems in the future
Please take some time to read the help page https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

try something like that in **sessionFactoryInitialisation** :

```
StandardServiceRegistry standardRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().configure(configFile).build();       
Metadata metadata =new MetadataSources(standardRegistry).getMetadataBuilder().build();  
sessionFactory = metadata.getSessionFactoryBuilder().build();
return sessionFactory;
```

Comment: How would that solve auto-creation ?